# ActiveMQ Artemis Thread dump

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a problem with ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.10.0 which is running on a docker. That's exactly a threading problem (logs below). At some point in the logs, I see this entry:

```
Component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer is expired on path 0
```

After that there is a entry which announced broker process will be killed:

```
AMQ224079: The process for the virtual machine will be killed, as component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer@51b01960 is not responsive
```

Later, there are a series of entries with thread process id, since id=2, to thread id 200 (i.e. to the value which is set variable `thread-pool-max-size =200 scheduled-thread-pool-max-size= 20` as described in [the docs](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/thread-pooling.html)).

On the [Artemis website](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/perf-tuning.html) I found that the broker can be turned off if it is in an unstable state.

Why that happen?

Logs:

```
 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalMeasure] Component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer is expired on path 0
 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224079: The process for the virtual machine will be killed, as component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.buffer.TimedBuffer@51b01960 is not responsive
 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222199: Thread dump: *******************************************************************************
Complete Thread dump
"Reference Handler" Id=2 RUNNABLE
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Native Method)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:241)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:213)


"Finalizer" Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@1d3b0b50
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@1d3b0b50
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:170)


"Signal Dispatcher" Id=4 RUNNABLE


"Common-Cleaner" Id=18 TIMED_WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@a9de548
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@a9de548
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:148)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:134)


"oneagentsubpathsender 1.189.238.20200508-120527" Id=20 RUNNABLE (in native)


"oneagentperiodiceventsmanaged" Id=21 RUNNABLE (in native)


"oneagentautosensor" Id=22 RUNNABLE


"oneagentperiodicurls" Id=23 RUNNABLE (in native)


"oneagentperiodicrequests" Id=24 RUNNABLE (in native)


"ActiveMQ Artemis Server Shutdown Timer" Id=27 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@3cc6ec06
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@3cc6ec06
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:553)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)

"Thread-0 (-scheduled-threads)" Id=29 RUNNABLE
        at java.management@11.0.5/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
        at java.management@11.0.5/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:502)
        at java.management@11.0.5/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:490)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ThreadDumpUtil.threadDump(ThreadDumpUtil.java:47)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.threadDump(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1022)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.lambda$initializeCriticalAnalyzer$0(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:678)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$$Lambda$127/0x00000001002df840.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalAnalyzerImpl.fireAction(CriticalAnalyzerImpl.java:155)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalAnalyzerImpl.check(CriticalAnalyzerImpl.java:140)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical.CriticalAnalyzerImpl$1.run(CriticalAnalyzerImpl.java:53)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent$2.run(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:284)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent$3.run(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:294)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)

        Number of locked synchronizers = 1
        - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1b58ff9e


"Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@466cf502)" Id=35 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@350d7400
        at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@350d7400
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor$ThreadPoolQueue.poll(ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor.java:112)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor$ThreadPoolQueue.poll(ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor.java:45)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)



"Thread-0 (activemq-netty-threads)" Id=112 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync@50ab59d6
        at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync@50ab59d6
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:917)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1240)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$WriteLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:959)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreImpl.page(PagingStoreImpl.java:835)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.addToPage(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:2074)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.processRoute(PostOfficeImpl.java:1308)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.route(PostOfficeImpl.java:1003)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.route(PostOfficeImpl.java:894)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.doSend(ServerSessionImpl.java:2073)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl@7805129
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.send(ServerSessionImpl.java:1712)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl@7805129
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.send(ServerSessionImpl.java:1651)
        -  locked org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl@7805129
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl.send(ServerSessionImpl.java:1643)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQSession.lambda$sendShouldBlockProducer$0(AMQSession.java:453)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQSession$$Lambda$274/0x0000000100597840.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.paging.impl.PagingStoreImpl.checkMemory(PagingStoreImpl.java:728)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQSession.sendShouldBlockProducer(AMQSession.java:504)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.amq.AMQSession.send(AMQSession.java:415)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection$CommandProcessor.processMessage(OpenWireConnection.java:1570)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.visit(ActiveMQMessage.java:768)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection.bufferReceived(OpenWireConnection.java:293)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:654)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:796)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:427)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:328)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)


"Thread-29 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@466cf502)" Id=200 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@350d7400
        at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@350d7400
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor$ThreadPoolQueue.poll(ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor.java:112)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor$ThreadPoolQueue.poll(ActiveMQThreadPoolExecutor.java:45)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1053)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)


"Scheduler-143999341" Id=202 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2a25f629
        at java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2a25f629
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1170)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base@11.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


"Thread-1 (activemq-netty-threads)" Id=2344 RUNNABLE (in native)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:114)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:276)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
```

Comment: Why that happen ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue, as far as I can tell doesn't really have anything to do with threading. The issue is, as the error message indicates, that the "TimedBuffer is expired on path 0" or in other words "TimedBuffer@51b01960 is not responsive." The "TimedBuffer" is the component which is responsible for flushing data to disk, and it's taking too long to flush data so the broker's "critical analyzer" shuts the broker down and emits a thread dump for debugging purposes.

The "critical analyzer" is a service within the broker which monitors important tasks and if those tasks take too long to complete then the critical analyzer will take action. The default `broker.xml` contains this configuration for the critical analyzer:

```xml
<critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
<critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
<critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
<critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
```

Therefore, every 60 seconds the critical analyzer will check various components and if any of them have stalled for 120 seconds (i.e. 2 minutes) then it will stop the broker. You will need to restart the broker manually or, depending on your platform, if the broker is acting as a "service" then it could be automatically restarted. You can read more about the critical analyzer in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/critical-analysis.html).

Comment: Does HALT mean that broker will be stopped or restarted? Also, TimedBuffer flushes data to disk. Is this part of the HA using a shared file sore? I was this error recently and am trying to understand the cause.

Comment: I updated my answer to address the first part of your comment. I'm not really sure what you're asking about about HA. The `TimedBuffer` is used to flush all data to disk whether that's locally or on a remote, shared disk. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I have these default settings, and Artemis enabled on systemctl. This error appeared last night, and it looks like Artemis restarted itself. For the TimedBuffer, I'm trying to understand if this error is due to the NFS mounted file system we use for the data folder, for HA.

Comment: To be clear, the platform must have restarted the broker as Artemis itself doesn't have any restart functionality in this situation. I'm still not sure if I addressed your question or not about HA/NFS.